# Unknown Verilog error asking for End after else

Tags: verilog

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)
begin
if(~rst)
Tp <= 0 ;

    else 
    begin 
         if(g3 == 255)
          sum_x <= sum_x + x3;

         else
         begin
               if((x3 == 0) && (y3 == 0))
               Tp<=0;
               sum_x=0;
               x4 = quotient1;

                else
                begin
                     if (x3 == 200)
                         r4 = 200;
                         g4 = 200;
                         b4 = 0;
                 end  
         end 
    end
end
endmodule
```

Mine has a different error compare to the previous question i asked which was solve by adding `end` for every `begin`. 
I followed wilcroft way of coding and the problem still exist

Comment: it doesn't matter, this is exactly the same issue.

Comment: the problem may be the same but i tried the solution and it didnt work as u can see above i use what you taught me by adding a end at each begin but it didnt solve it .

Comment: that was why i asked using the same tittle if that's cause misunderstanding i can delete the old post

Comment: Normally, `if`'s and `'else`'s only apply to one statement. You use `begin`'s and `end`'s just like the braces (`{` and `}`) in C/C++ or Java - they define a block of code to be executed instead. However, it's important that they be matched correctly - hence the proper indenting I suggested below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely matching your `begin`'s with `end`'s - they're like braces (`{` and `}`) in C/C++, in that they need to match up with the structures they're capturing. As such, it's helpful to indent them accordingly.

Properly indented, your `always` block is as follows:

```
always@(posedge clk or negedge rst)        //Line 34
begin                                      
    if(~rst)                               
        Tp <= 0 ;                          //Line 37
    else 
    begin                                 
        if(g3 == 255)                      //Line 40
            sum_x <= sum_x + x3;
        else
        begin                              //Line 43
            if((x3 == 0) && (y3 == 0))
                Tp<=0;
            sum_x=0;                       //Line 46
            x4 = quotient1;
        end
    end                                    //Line 49
end
endmodule
```

Placing an `else` on line 49 (and moving the `end` down accordingly) gives the error you're seeing, because the if statement in the current block (Lines 39-49, pre-insertion) already has an `else` clause on line 42!

Use proper indenting, and double-check that line 49 is where it should go, and maybe verify the other `if`'s while you're at it, just to be sure :)

---

Addendum:
It's important to note that in Verilog this:

```
begin
if (<condition>)
    a = 1;
b = 1;
end
```

is different than

```
if (<condition>)
begin
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
end
```

In the first example, the `b = 1;` line is **always** executed, regardless of the outcome of the `if`. In the second, both statements depend on the result of the `if`.

`If` (and `else`) only apply to the first statement that follows it, or a group of statments if that first "statement" is a `begin`. Use `begin` and `end` to group only the statements run as a result of the `if`, like in the second example.

Comment: the only problem that i encounter is only when i add a new else statement which will ask me to add another end

Comment: which `if` line are you trying to apply the `else` to?

Comment: error only pop out when i try adding
    else (49)
     begin
         if (x3 == 200)
              r3 = 200;
              g3 = 200;
              b3 = 0;

Comment: which `if` are you trying to match the `else` to? As your HDL was written in your question, every `if` has a matching `else` except the one on line 44. Adding an `else` in a location other than line 46 means in doesn't have an `if` to be matched against.

Comment: i tried ur method and add the new statement the way u said but the problem still occur the same

Comment: @Dom Could you update the question with what you have tried, and please correct the indentation, using spaces not tabs. Most issues like this become clear when correctly indented.

Comment: @Dom - see the addendum to my answer above - I've tried to better explain how the `begin`-`end` block structure works, since it sounds like you might be using it incorrectly.

Comment: i had a misunderstanding of my work.. i was suppose to add the code to another module but i didn't after i take a break and recap i found out my mistake sorry for the trouble and thanks for your help wilcroft i also understand my mistake from it thru your guideance

Comment: sorry can i ask if i were to declare a `wire` as an `reg`
for example `reg` clken1;
`.clken ( clken1 )`
what will happen?

Comment: `reg`s are used for signals assigned a value in an `always` block. `wire`s are used for siganls assigned a value by use of an `assign` statement or as the output of a submodule. Inputs to submodules can be either. A signal can be a `wire` or a `reg`, but not both. 
(Next time, make a new question please)

Comment: i could not make any more question due to the fact that this post was downvoted :) sorry bro ! but thanks for the help